# Embedding Redux framework 4 in theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frameworks, beta, redux-framework

Someone have difficult to embedding Redux framework 4 in theme without installing plugin?

Old Redux framework work ok, but this new version doesn't work.
I think something is wrong in the folder path.

for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="redux-admin-theme-css-css" href="https://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my_theme/includes/redux-framework/ReduxCore/assets/css/colors/fresh/colors.css?ver=4.0.1.1.1551186467" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Redux try to load files always in plugin folder `https://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/`

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try again. We just pushed a fix today on some path issues. ;)